# How do I sync my ps4?

Tags: ps4, psn

When I got my ps4 I couldn't create an account for some reason. I had 7 games on it. Now that I created my account, in my profile it says that I have only 2 games. How can I sync my profile with my games and trophies?

I could install an add-on for Tekken 7 but when i wanted to install a DLCfor Dragon Age it keep saying "Can't find application" and asks to search the store. What should I do? Will updating the game solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking is very ambiguous, without more information or screenshots I cannot come to a conclusion as to why your games are not in sync with your PSN profile. There isn’t a magic button to do this.

But here is what you can try, logging off and logging back in PSN, wait a few days because I know sometimes it takes a while for the data to be in sync on PSN. Also set your current system as your Primary PS4 system, you can do this in settings. Although I doubt this will help.

If all else fails you can certainly contact the PlayStation support, use their live chat and try to resolve this issue.